# How to rename the $v name?

Tags: php, foreach

Here is my code ,output and doubt ....

```
<?php
$csvData = file_get_contents("http://feed2.abc.com/PriceWs/PriceSnap.asmx/PriceUpdate?item=GC-APR16,SI-MAY16,PA-JUN16,PL-APR16,CL-APR16,BRCL-MAY16,NG-APR16,HO-APR16,HG-MAY16,CC-MAY16,KC-MAY16,CN-MAY16,CT-MAY16,WH-MAY16,SB-MAY16,SY-MAY16,BO-MAY16,&col=last,bid,ask,high,low");
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

foreach($array as $k=>$v){

    ?>


    <table border="1">

<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $v[0]; ?><td>
    <td> <?php echo $v[1]; ?><td>
        <td> <?php echo $v[2]; ?><td>


        </tr>`enter code here`


<?php
}

?>
```

---

OUTPUT WILL BE LIKE THIS:

GC-APR16        1234.40     1233.30 
        SI-MAY16        15.180      15.180
        PA-JUN16        538.10      539.10
        PL-APR16        954.50      955.60
        HG-MAY16        2.0750      2.0745
        CC-MAY16        2851.0      2849.0
        KC-MAY16        119.90      119.90
        CN-MAY16        361.75      361.50
        CT-MAY16        59.44       59.42
        WH-MAY16        460.25      460.00
        SB-MAY16        14.33       14.33
        SY-MAY16        905.00      905.00
        BO-MAY16        33.87       33.86

### HERE IS MY DOUBT:

INSTEAD OF GC-APR16 need to display "GOLD", SI-MAY16 need to display "SILVER"

PLEASE HELP....

MANY THANKS

Comment: What has this to do with JS?

Comment: what is the logic behind that? you only need to change "GC-APR16" to gold and "SI-MAY16" to silver? you can do this with `str_replace` function.

Comment: use str_replace function

Comment: Thanks guys let me try...

Answer (score 0):

```
$v[0] = GC-APR16 1234.40 1233.30';

// get first two chars
$two_chars = substr($v[0]);

// "multi if-else"
switch($two_chars) {
    case 'GC': $new_tx = 'GOLD'; break;
    ...
    default: ; //show error
}

echo $new_tx;
```